# Random ants, need help with error in my thought process

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

I am trying to solve this problem: [Expected falling time of all $500$ random ants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493757/expected-falling-time-of-all-500-random-ants)
I need help with understanding why my thought process is flawed. (highlighted below)

> Question: 500 ants are randomly put on a 1-foot string (independent
> uniform distribution for each ant between 0 and 1). Each ant randomly
> moves toward on end of the string (equal probability to the left or
> the right) at constant speed of 1 foot/minute until it falls of a t
> one end of the string. Also assume that the size of the ant is
> infinitely small. When two ants collide head-on, they both immediately
> change directions and keep on moving at 1 foot/min. What is the
> expected time for all ants to fall off the string?

I totally get that when ants collide they exchange labels, so we just consider that ants never collide and keep on walking till one end of the string.

**My flawed thought process**: When an ant lands on a point "x" foot away it can go either left or right (equal probability). So expected time taken by it is 0.5*x + 0.5*(1-x) = 0.5, which is independent of x. So all ants regardless where they land will take an expected time of 0.5min.

However the solution says that the time taken is x or 1-x and we can just solve for expected value of maximum value of 500 X's. ( because x , 1-x are symmetric.) .

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3):

Both of you are correct:

If $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, then

- The expected value of $X$ is $0.5$
- The expected value of $1-X$ is also $0.5$, (and $1-X$ is also a uniform random distribution on the interval $[0,1]$, just as $X$ was)
- The expected value of $0.5*X + 0.5*(1-X)$ is also still $0.5$. (though it is not longer a uniform distribution but a constant).

The interesting part of the qeustion is, how do you determine the expected maximum of 500 (independent) copies of $X$? For this, it is not sufficient to know the expected value of each individual $X$. The distribution is important here.

Comment: probably I wrote it wrong. the 0.5 in 0.5*x + 0.5*(1-x) was meant to signify the probability of going right and probability of going left.
I am getting the intuition that the final distribution looks different, but still unable to understand it. I understand that p.d.f. of max(Xi) is different and can take out the value 500/501. But how does that relate here? Sorry, if i am asking dumb questions

Comment: do you mean to say that the final answer is 0.5*max(Xi) + 0.5*max(1-Xi) ?

Comment: actually, thats true. The expected value of $\max(X_i)$ is the same as the expected value of $0.5 \max(X_i)+0.5\max(1-X_i)$.

Comment: Totally makes sense. I get it now. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: you're welcome. I wasnt sure if I wrote something useful for you. Stochastics is hard to wrap ones head around sometimes ;)

Comment: haha yeah! that part where you said " max(Xi) is the same as the expected value of 0.5max(Xi)+0.5max(1−Xi)" did it for me. Actually I had solved this question around 10 days back on my own but today totally went off a different chain of thought. Just need tons of practice to weed out such thinking errors :)